# Smallest intermediate field containing two intermediate fields

Tags: field-theory

Let $K/k$ be a field extension and $A$ and $B$ intermediate fields. Further, let $C$ be the smallest intermediate field that contains $A$ and $B$.

(1) Show that $A/k$ and $B/k$ separable $\implies$ $C/k$ is separable

From (1) deduce

(2) The subset $\{x\in K \mid x \; \text{separable over}\; k\}$ is an intermediate field of $K/k$

---

As for (1) I would argue as follows:

Let $\alpha \in A, \beta \in B$. There is a theorem stating that when $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are separable over $k$ then so is $k(\alpha,\beta)$. But this means that $\alpha + \beta, \alpha - \beta, \alpha\beta, \frac{\alpha}{\beta}$ are separable over $k$. Since $C$ consists of all finite sums, differences, products and quotients of elements of $A$ and $B$, it follows that C is separable over $k$.

Is this argument correct?

As for (2) I would argue the exact same way as in (1). So I don't quite see the necessity of making the detour via (1).

Am I missing something?